# My PC crashed during coding and now i am confused // java // Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sikuli

So, i had my little programm running almost fine when suddenly my pc crashed and nothing was saved. Now my script is at a point where i simpely don't understand it anymore (as i am new to coding and in order to solve my problem i made it even worse), i just can't get it to work anymore.
This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.CENSORED.CENSORED</groupId>
  <artifactId>CENSORED</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>CENSORED</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Before everything crashed and i messed up the code could do the following:
- It imported sikuli (i think this works just as any other jar. Btw, is there anything i can fuck up because i am using 1.1.0 but i found higher ones on maven but wasn't sure what to do with them);
- it imported my imgs folder (This is what my project looks in eclipse: http://prntscr.com/fa7kii)
- and it opened the App.java i programmed

Atm when i am running my App.java everything is fine, but i can't export it. The UI is not showing up (i think i did not set up mainclass properly); but i am trying to solve this problem now for like 3 hours and i simpely am that confused that i don't know what do do anymore. I deleted my code multiple times, and this is what's left over.
Could you please just fix my pom.xml file and explain me how?

I also have this under the overview: http://prntscr.com/fa7laj
I think i do have a few plugins installed, do i have to uninstall them?

Please help me, i am really confused...

I want to have a jar i can click and need nothing else, which then searches the image inside and clicks on it.
I do have the App.java code done, but i don't think it's required here.

Sorry for my bad english, i am from germany.

Bit more information(idk if required):
I am working with eclipse and maven. I do have a windows 7 pc.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Solved it. Thanks for downvoting.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.CENSORED</groupId>
  <artifactId>CENSORED</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SWBOT</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.CENSORED</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```